# SQL 1 value -> split to 4

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to build a query which based on inserting ip values in such table. It's mmorpg game database-based.

So here's the query

```
declare @ip1 varchar (max)
declare @ip2 varchar (max)
declare @ip3 varchar (max)
declare @ip4 varchar (max)

set @ip1 = 'xx'--1.IP 
set @ip2 = 'xxx' -- 2.IP
set @ip3 = 'xx' -- 3.IP
set @ip4 = 'xx' --4.IP

if exists (select IP3 from _PrivilegedIP where IP3 = @ip3)
begin
   print 'Shit, this IP already exist'
end
else if exists (select IP4 from _PrivilegedIP where IP4 = @ip4)
begin
   print 'Shit, this IP already exist'
end
else
begin
     insert into _PrivilegedIP values(@ip1, @ip2, @ip3, @ip4, @ip1, @ip2, @ip3, @ip4)
     print @ip1+'.'+@ip2+'.'+@ip3+'.'+@ip4+'has been added successfully---Omg123'
end
```

Now, I'm trying to do it like

set @id='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'

and then, it'll split the values between dots and update in table as the query .

Any help?

Comment: For which DB are you scripting for? MS SQL?. Add as Tag to question when question is DB specific.

Comment: `print 'Shit, this IP already exist` <-- is this really your output?

Answer (score 2):

The [`PARSENAME()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) function is your friend...

```
DECLARE @ip VARCHAR(50) = '123.124.125.126'

DECLARE @ip1 VARCHAR(10) = PARSENAME(@ip, 4) 
DECLARE @ip2 VARCHAR(10) = PARSENAME(@ip, 3)
DECLARE @ip3 VARCHAR(10) = PARSENAME(@ip, 2)
DECLARE @ip4 VARCHAR(10) = PARSENAME(@ip, 1)

IF NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM _PrivilegedIP
  WHERE IP4 = @ip4
  OR IP3 = @ip3
)
INSERT _PrivilegedIP (IP1, IP2, IP3, IP4)
VALUES (@ip1, @ip2, @ip3, @ip4)
```

Click [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6c8d/2) to see it in action at SQL Fiddle.